Как по нажатию кнопки открыть окно в котором открыта страница, а в ней открыта другая страница? WPF
Добрый день пользователи данной площадки, возник трудный и нерешаемый у меня вопрос с которым мне не помог и Чат GPT, Суть проблемы вот в чём при выходе из полноэкранного режима на странице Филиалы и Офисы хочется чтобы открывалось окно MainWindow на которой открыта страница Мои документы на которой открыта страница Филиалы и офисы, (получилось только вызвать MainWindow и открыть Филиалы и офисы, но нет промежуточного этапа Мои документы), ранее делал открытие Общей информации но там проще путь (Полноэкранное окно=>MainWindow=>Мои документы) вот прикрепляю весь необходимый код: Код из Полноэкранного окна
public static class СжиманиеОкна
{
    public static string Счёт { get; set; }
}
private void Квадрат_клик(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /*if (СжиманиеОкна.Счёт == "Общая_информация")
    {
        //Это вам не нужно но оно работает
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.Show();
        // Вызов метода Окно 2 для открытия страницы "Мои Документы"
        window.МоиДокументы();
    }*/ 
    else if (СжиманиеОкна.Счёт == "ФилиалыОфисы")
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.Show();
        window.МоиДокументы();
    }
    this.Close();
}

private void ФилиалыОфисы_клик(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    СжиманиеОкна.Счёт = "ФилиалыОфисы";
    Сборник1.Content = new ФилиалыОфисыСтраница();
}

Код из MainWindow
public void МоиДокументы()
{
    /*if (СжиманиеОкна.Счёт == "Общая_информация")
    {
        //Это вам не надо но оно работает
        Сборник1.Navigate(new Страница2МоиДокументы());
    }*/
    else if (СжиманиеОкна.Счёт == "ФилиалыОфисы")
    {
        //Сборник1.Navigate(new СтраницаФилиалыИОфисы());
        Страница2МоиДокументы страница2 = new Страница2МоиДокументы();
        страница2.ФилиалыИОфисы();
    }
}

Код из Филиалы и офисы
public void ФилиалыИОфисы()
{
    Сборник1.Navigate(new Страница2());
}

При запуске и нажатии на кнопку Квадрат_клик открывает MainWindow. Если использовать код то тогда получиться вывести Филиалы и офисы но он будет съехавший из за того что должен находиться в Мои документы. Заранее спасибо за помощь!Сборник1.Navigate(new СтраницаФилиалыИОфисы());

Вы можете попробовать использовать паттерн mvvm так используете wpf, в следствии сделать переменную типа ViewModelBase и забиндить ее в контент окна и по нажатию на кнопку контент окна будет заменятся на нужный вам
